# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS flickers and shows some codes while booting, but starts at end

Tags: 18.04

When I start my laptop Dell Inspiron 3521, the ubuntu screen flickers and some random codes appears and then the lock screen appears. Can anyone help me fix this problem ?

Comment: What do you wish to change, exactly?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't want that flickering on my screen